# create hyperlink in gridview asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

My code is in c# asp.net 3.5

In the following code the "Msg" has many words with spaces and characters (eg:Failed to prepare Sync Favorites : Directory does not exist: \STL-FNP-02\ryounes$\Sync\Favorites). This "Msg" is pulled from database to a gridview. I am not able to create hyperlink for this "Msg" in gridview. Since it has spaces it is not creating hyperlink.

I need to create hyperlink for this "Msg" and latter use it in linq query.

I think one shud either use eval or url encoder. I am not sure how to do it. Can anyone say how to go about it?

```
 <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="Msg" HeaderText="Msg" DataNavigateUrlFields="Msg"   
  DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Sync.aspx?Msg={0}" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to get around it is to use something like

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Msg"> 
    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text='<%# HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("Msg")) %>' NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("Msg")%>' />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Not 100% certain that the syntax is correct but you get the general idea

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't create the link as it is not a valid URL, rather than using a hyperlink column most likely you are going to need to migrate to a template and manage it yourself, or at minimum do some formatting on it.

I would be cautious regardless of making that a hyperlink, where is it going to go anway?

If there is a specific place based on message that you should be going, calculate that BEFORE you bind to the grid...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to url-encode the string so that the words and spaces can exist as one variable in the query string. Take a look at this function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx